# Tangential forces on the boundary in Abaqus

Tags: mechanical-engineering

In Abaqus I print the problem's geometry of a plate 2D with a crack at the edge, bound on the left side in the x-direction and subjected to uniform effort in y-direction (uniform pressure - perpendicular to the two opposing edges) as shown in the figure:

[image]

How can I apply the tangential forces on the boundary as shown in the figure:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: care to explain why you think the abaqus tag is inappropriate?

Answer (score 1):

In Abaqus to apply a shear constant shear force on a surface you need to construct a **Surface Traction** load condition. This is an option in the *Load* module. You will need to supply the direction and magnitude of the shear traction vector.